# Add error message if duplicate record exist in MVC Popup Form

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a popup window called AddNew will display when the user click a button called add New. The button itself has number of field called TRN and DOB. The problem that i have now that i am trying to display error message when the user try to add duplicate TRN but unfortunately no error message display only if the required field is empty.

Is there anyway i could display the duplicate error message in validation summary like displaying in required field and hold all the previous entered value in the form. Please advise. Thank you

Here is the code that i have so far. Thank you

**Index.cshtml**

```
<input type="button" id="btnAddNew" style="height:50px; font-size:14px; width:95px; background-color:#3399FF; white-space: normal;" class="k-button" title="AddNew" value="Add New" />

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnAddNew').click(function () {
     window.open('@Url.Action("AddNew", "Details")', 'AddProduct', 'height=' + (window.screen.height - 450) + ',width=950,left=' + (window.screen.width - 5) + ',top=10,status=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes');
        });
});

</script>
```

**AddNew.cshtml (window popup)**

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutNoMenu.cshtml";

}

<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

@model HHIMS_Web_App.Models.CModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "New Product";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Details", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmAsset" }))
 {
    ViewContext.FormContext.ValidationSummaryId = "valSumId";
    @Html.ValidationSummary(false, "Please fix the following errors:", new Dictionary<string, object> { { "id", "valSumId" } });

    <fieldset id="AddNew">


        <div>
            <div class="addInfo">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TRN)
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TRN)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TRN, "*")
            </div>
             &nbsp;
            <div class="AddSmallBox">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DOB)
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DOB)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DOB, "*")

            </div>
     </div>






         <div>
                 <div class="smallAddAndCancel">
                    <input type="button" id="btnCancel" style="height:50px; width:85px; font-size:14px; background-color:#3399FF" class="k-button" title="Cancel" value="Cancel" onclick="window.close()" />
                    <input type="submit" id="btnSave" style="height:50px; width:85px; font-size:14px; background-color:#3399FF;white-space: normal" class="k-button" title="Save" value="Save"/>

                </div>
        </div>


    </fieldset>
}


<script type="text/javascript">


    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#datepicker").closest("span.k-datepicker").width(400);

        $('#btnSave').click(function () {

           var validation = $("#frmAsset"); 
            if (!validation.valid()) {
                return false;
            else
            {



                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: "@Url.Action("Create","Details")",
                        data: {

                            TRN: $("#TRN").val(),
                            DOB: $("#DOB").val(),



                        },

                            success: function () {
                            window.close()
                        }
                    });
            }
        });


    });




</script>
```

**Controller:**
[HttpPost]

```
public ActionResult Create(Cmodel)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                CheckDuplicateHRNExist(model);
                return RedirectToAction("AddNew");
            }
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                HH_DataAccessLayer.Consumers dalModel = new HH_DataAccessLayer.Consumers();
                Mapper.CreateMap<CModel, HH_DataAccessLayer.Consumers>();
                Mapper.Map(model, dalModel);
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException e)
        {
            var entry = e.Entries.Single();
            var clientValues = (CModel)entry.Entity;
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Validate TRN find if no duplicate TRN recorded
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="model"></param>


private void CheckDuplicateTRNExist(CModel model)
    {
        HEntities context = new HEntities();
        if (model.TRN != null)
        {
            var duplicateTRN = context.Consumers.Where(d => d.TRN == model.TRN).FirstOrDefault();
            if (duplicateTRN != null)
            {
                var errorMessage = String.Format("TRN is already exist.", duplicateTRN);
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, errorMessage);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Model**

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter TRN")]
        [DisplayName("TRN")]
        [StringLength(20)]
        public string TRN { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter or select Date of Birth")]
        [DisplayName("Date Of Birth")]
        public DateTime? DOB { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaking, ValidationSummary must be set to true to display custom errors.

Edit: to be complete:

In your AddNew.cshtml file, replace

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(false, "Please fix the following errors:", new Dictionary<string, object> { { "id", "valSumId" } });
```

With:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Please fix the following errors:", new Dictionary<string, object> { { "id", "valSumId" } });
```

Comment: It still the same, it only show the required validation error but not for duplicate record

Comment: Hmmm, odd. In that case, the only difference with my own code (which works) is that the ModelState.AddModelError part is in my ActionResult Create function. And that I just use @Html.ValidationSummary(true); without the second argument.

Comment: It is true. Now i am trying to create Validation in Model similar to required field. Any ideas?

Comment: Not really. I use it to catch any exceptions that are thrown when saving (I've put my business logic in my save). Other than the above mentioned differences, I do it in exactly the same way.

Comment: @Supermode: in your try catch DbUpdateConcurrencyException: maybe it is worth adding a ModelState.AddModelError here as well?